# Keep getting SqlException syntax error at end of ExecuteNonQuery(); Connection to SqlDb on local Network

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-insert

I keep getting `SqlException` syntax error at end of `ExecuteNonQuery();` Connection is to a SQL Server database on a virtual server in the local network.

[image: Screenshot of Error Message]

Comment: Before you write another line of code you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is classic example of sql injection. You should NEVER EVER EVER build up a string with user input and execute it. http://bobby-tables.com/ Not only would parameters prevent you from sql injection it almost certainly would fix the issue at hand.

Comment: Ok then.  I'm using a test DB with no real danger to actual data but it is obvious what parameterized queries are best practice.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah even in a test or dev environment it is better to use parameters. For one, you may copy and paste code and it prevents issues with all sort so of other things that are just painful to work with. You also should consider listing the columns in your insert statement. Not listing them becomes a real hassle when the table changes and suddenly your code is broken.

Comment: Any good articles/videos you could recommend?

Comment: Did you see the link in my first comment? It has languages on the left side and examples in all of them.

Comment: Also, it will help to paste this code here so that we can see the entirety of your sql statement. If you're not specifying your fields, then you are missing VALUES but we can't see the statement in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning the query to the  variable as below

```
string line1= (" Insert into PMRecordedSale("+.....)

SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
myConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DbConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(line1, myConnection);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Good advice...Look at the string in the debugger and cut and past it into MSSMS.